# How to adding Dynamic Methods at Runtime to Grails domain object without creating plugins?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In the ref documentation I found only example such as

```
class ExamplePlugin {
  def doWithDynamicMethods = { applicationContext ->
        application.controllerClasses.each { controllerClass ->
             controllerClass.metaClass.myNewMethod = {-> println "hello world" }
        }
  }
}
```

But I don't want to create plugin for such code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add your dynamic methods in the **grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy** file in the **init** closure, then they should be available at app startup.

Note that the dynamic methods you add this way won't be available in your unit tests. They will be available in integration tests and at run-time.

Comment: One thing you'll need with this approach is to add 'def grailsApplication' as a dependency injection in BootStrap.groovy so you have access to the artifacts. Then you can call 'grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each ...'

Answer (score 2):

you dont have to.  Just the innermost line of your example is necessary.  Assume you have

```
SomeDomain
```

as a class.  You can do

```
SomeDomain.metaClass.newMethod  = {-> // stuff }
```

now I am going to go verify this...;)

Edit -- I've verified this.  Just type the following into the groovy shell on the command line

```
class Example {}; Example.metaClass.newMethod = {-> println 'hello'}; def e = new Example(); e.newMethod()
```